# RxJS take operator not working with Angular app

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a resolver that fetches data from a service and passes that Observable object to the component which subscribes and implements the resolver.

```
resolve (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<NewsAPIArticle[]> {
    return this.newsAPIService.getNewsAPIArticles()
        .pipe(
            catchError(error => {
                this.alertify.error('Problem retrieving news');
                return of(null);
            }),
            take(5)
        );
}
```

In the ngOnInit of the component, I get the data, save it to a local array, and console log the array.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.articles = data['news']['articles'];
      console.log(this.articles);
      this.language = 'en';
    });
  }
```

However, instead of console logging 5 things the resolver should "take" from the observable as I understand it, the array comes back with 20 objects. What am I doing wrong in the take rxjs operator? I don't want all 20 responses, only maybe 5.

[image]

Comment: `this.newsAPIService.getNewsAPIArticles().pipe(switchMap(r => r), take(5))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`take(5)` means it will take 5 items from the stream. The array is a single item in the stream as the observable is of type `NewsAPIArticle[]`. If the observable was of type `NewsAPIArticle`, and the stream emitted multiple articles, `take(5)` would behave as you expect, but as it is, the service you call emits all articles at once.

Comment: Oh I see. So 'take' is considering that giant array as one single item returned from the observable, so there isn't even 5 to 'take'.

Comment: Exactly. You've got it.

Answer (score 3):

You should use map with slice,

```
 .pipe(...
   map(x => x.slice(0,5))
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting just using slicke here. I'm not sure about using it in the pipe function, maybe there is a way to have that work, but for me, I needed to simply use slice as part of the subscribe response, like this:
        .subscribe(
          (x) => {
            this.studentData = x.slice(0, 5);
          },

Comment: ** just using 'slice' here** obviously